# Correct Bios Update for Asrock X470 Motherboard with 3rd Gen AMD Processor?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, updates, compatibility

I'm doing a new build which features an Asrock x470 Taichi motherboard and an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 CPU.

The [support page](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X470%20Taichi/index.asp#CPU) for the BIOS says the Ryzen 5 3600 is supported "since BIOS version 3.40"

However, the page with links to [BIOS updates](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X470%20Taichi/index.asp#BIOS) shows a more recent version 3.60 that seemed intended for Matisse CPU like the Ryzen 5 3600.

To complicate matters further, I did a little more digging and found a [separate page](https://www.asrock.com/support/cpu.asp?s=AM4&u=607) listing CPUs and associated BIOS versions that support them which suggests that the Ryzen 5 3600 isn't supported *since* version 3.40 but, instead, *only* on 3.40.

I used an older CPU to flash to 3.60 for the Ryzen 5 3600 and the post code was showing "CPU error" for both CPUs which suggests that 3.60 was a bad choice and that I'm screwed. (Clearing the CMOS hasn't helped and I assume this is because it clears and resets to 3.60.)

I tried contacting Asrock customer support but it's been 3 days since their automated "we'll be in touch soon" email.

Should I have chosen BIOS version 3.40 instead of 3.60 or is there some other problem (perhaps with the CPU itself) that I'm experiencing?

Comment: Have you cleared the CMOS after the BIOS update?

Comment: If this is an actual firmware comparability issue then 3.40 would have the same comparability issues as 3.60 appears to have with your hardware.  If the support page by the manufacture says support has existed since 3.40 then that support exists with 3.60

Comment: @ess I disconnected the powercord and pushed the reset CMOS button on the motherboard (held it down for a few seconds). That didn't seem to help and I assume the reason is that it "resets" to the newly flashed 3.60 BIOS.

Comment: Bios versions are cumulative, the include updates from previous versions, I have never seen them remove support for a cpu once its added.